# How to reset wifi settings?

Tags: wireless, settings, reset

I was experimenting with WiFi settings and after that I've set everything back but doesn't work as it was before.

Is there a way to reset wifi setting as it was at the first start?

Answer (score 0):

This restores several control center missing features

update libraries first

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install or reinstall gnome control center

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```